# How to handle redux-saga and save user input data in Formik to Redux

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux, react-hooks, redux-saga

I'm making very simple Login app for learning react and react-native also, my goal is get user input, then compare these value to a custom fake api file that contain user and password value, then save in `AsyncStorage`(or `localStorage`) for authentication . So i search the internet for what i'm going to do, here is the one that match what i'm looking for , but there are few things i  really don't understand how this code work. In this code, there are something make me confuse for week, so many question in my head so i really need some help. Here is the code:

First he has a Redux Action like this in his code

```
//Action.js
export const LoginRequested = (username,password) => {
  return {
    type: 'LOG_IN_REQUEST',
    data: {
      username,
      password,
    },
  };
};

export const LoginSuccessed = (data) => {
  return {
    type: 'LOGIN_SUCCESS',
    data,
  };
};

export const LoginFailed = (data) => {
  return {
    type: 'LOG_IN_FAILURE',
    data,
  };
};

export const Logout = (data) => {
  return {
    type: 'LOG_OUT',
    data
  };
};
```

But what make me confuse is

**Question 1:** **what is `data` here? What is this `data` used for?**

I mean i can understand that in `LoginRequested` , data is username and password, so i guess username and password store here, but in `loginSuccessed` and `LoginFailed`, i don't get it, what is data here

Here is the  Reducer

```
const initialState = {
  isLoading: false,
  authen: false
};

export const loginReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'LOG_IN_REQUEST':
      {
        //console.log('action : LOG IN REQUEST');
        return {
          isLoading: true,
          authen: false
        }
      }
    case 'LOG_IN_SUCCESS':
      {
        //console.log('action : LOG IN SUCCESS');
        return {
          isLoading: false,
          authen: true
        };
      }
    case 'LOG_IN_FAILURE':
      {
        //console.log('action : LOG IN FAILURE');
        return initialState;
      }
    case 'LOG_OUT':
      {
        //console.log('action : LOG OUT');
        return initialState;
      }
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

And to the reducer, so :

**Question 2:**  **what do  `isLoading` and `authen( maybe authentication)` do ??** .

I can understand it present for login status, is that right? but i can't link how he use there code( i see him  use 'LOGIN_SUCCESS' once in saga below but i don't get it)

Here is the store:

```
//store.js
const sagaMiddleware = createSagaMiddleware();
const store = createStore(rootReducer, applyMiddleware(sagaMiddleware)); //rootReducer is a combined reducer file, i don't show it here, but he have only one Reducer like above code
sagaMiddleware.run(rootSaga);

export default store;
```

I understand this, this is how redux apply middleware.

Now is Saga part

```
//saga.js
import { Alert } from 'react-native';
import { call, put, takeLatest } from 'redux-saga/effects';
//import axios from 'axios';
import { fetchLoginData } from '../../server/loginApi';

export function* loginMainSaga() {
  yield takeLatest('LOG_IN_REQUEST', loginSaga);
}

function* saveDataToStorage(data) {
  try {
      AsyncStorage.setItem(
          'userData',
          JSON.stringify({
              username: data.username,
              password: data.password }))  
      } catch(e) {
      console.log('error save to Storage');
  }
};

function* loginSaga(action) {
    const response = yield call(fetchLoginData);
    const resData = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(response));
    
    const usernameAuth = String(resData.data[0].username);
    const passwordAuth = String(resData.data[0].password); 

    if (String(action.data.username) === usernameAuth)
    {
      if (String(action.data.password) === passwordAuth)
      {
        //console.log('loginSaga LOG_IN_SUCCESS');
        yield put({type: 'LOG_IN_SUCCESS'});
        saveDataToStorage(action.data);
      }
      else
      {
        const error = 'Password is incorrect'
        Alert.alert('Failed', error, [{ text: 'Ok', style: 'cancel' }] );
        //console.log('loginSaga LOG_IN_FAILURE');
        yield put({type: 'LOG_IN_FAILURE'});
      }
    } else {
      const error = 'Username is incorrect'
      Alert.alert('Failed', error, [{ text: 'Ok', style: 'cancel' }] );
      //console.log('loginSaga LOG_IN_FAILURE');
      yield put({type: 'LOG_IN_FAILURE'});
      
    }
}
```

I can understand that, `loginMainSaga()` is to get lastest `username` and `password` store in redux and compare to the one in Json file by using `loginSaga`. `SaveDatatoStorage` mean you save username and password to `AsyncStorage`.

**Question 3 : Is my above logic right ? and `action` in `loginSaga` function here is a random variable word or point direct to `action in redux reducer`?**

And the most confuse part is loginScreen:

He split code to different components, just basic style and component of Formik, detail [here](https://github.com/BotLineTia/AwesomeProject/tree/main/src/components):

Here is the login screen

```
function LoginScreen(props) {

    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    const loginHandler =({username, password}) => {
        dispatch(
            LoginRequested(username,password)
          );
      };

    const isLoading = useSelector(state => {
        //console.log('state.Login.isLoading ' + state.Login.isLoading);
        return state.Login.isLoading;
    });

    return(
        <Screen style={styles.container}>
            <MaterialCommunityIcons name="wechat" color="black" size={200} />
            <Text style={styles.title}>SIGN IN HERE</Text>

            <AppForm
                initialValues={{username: '', password: ''}}
                onSubmit={loginHandler}
                validationSchema={validateSchema}>
                <AppFormField
                    name="username"
                    placeholder="Username"
                    icon="account"
                    autoCapitalize="none"
                    autoCorrect={false}
                    textContentType="nickname"
                    width="75%"
                    ></AppFormField>
                <AppFormField
                    name="password"
                    placeholder="Password"
                    icon="lock"
                    autoCapitalize="none"
                    autoCorrect={false}
                    secureTextEntry
                    textContentType="password"
                    width="75%"></AppFormField>
                {isLoading ? 
                (
                <ActivityIndicator size="large" color={'black'} />
                ) : (
                <SubmitBtn title="Sign in" color={'black'} width="75%" />
                )}    
            </AppForm>

        <View style={styles.registerContainer}>
            <Text style={{color: 'black'}}>Don't have an account?</Text>
            <Text style={{color: 'black'}} onPress={() => null}> SIGN UP </Text>
            </View>
        </Screen>
    );
}
```

I don't understand how can he get `user` and `password` ,
my first question in this file is:

**Question 4: Why `loginHandler` const have `{}` in `({username,password})` , why not use `(username,password)`?**

And the most thing make me have a headache and can't stop think about it for this week :

**Question 5 :How can he get `user` and `password` when he onSubmit???? He use `loginHandler`, but how can he add `username` and `password`, , how he catch which input was `username`, which is `password` , if i have 3 form input, how can this handle? is there something special with `formik onSubmit`????**

Here is the full code : [FULL CODE](https://github.com/BotLineTia/AwesomeProject)

Please help, your help is very precious for me right now and maybe can solve problem of other newcomer like me. Thank you so so much

Comment: Please help :((

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The first set of functions are called action creators. They take any data, and create an action that packages that data with the action `type`. For `LoginRequested()` the payload is `username` and `password`. Not all actions need to have a payload however and so for `Logout()` you may be able to exclude any paramaters from that action creator.
2. Reducer's take actions produced by action creators (such as `LoginRequested` and `logout`), and calculate an update to the store's state. From the code sample you have provided `isLoading` and `authen` are two boolean properties that are being read from some actions, and stored in the redux store via these reducers. To understand where these values originate, you'll need to debug where actions with these types are created: `'LOG_IN_REQUEST'`
3. You are correct that actions have a `type` property that is any random identifier. It's common practice to use a phrase-like `string` data type to make it more readable.
4. `loginHandler` is being passed as the function that takes the `<AppForm />` `onSubmit`. The `onSubmit` of any HTML based form will pass a set of key-value pairs in an object, and thus `loginHandler` must take it's arguments in the format `{}`
5. You are correct, it is because of `onSubmit`. This function will take the `name` of every HTML input element within it's HTML node, and pair it with the respective element's `value`.

```
                <AppFormField name="username" />
                <AppFormField name="password" />
```

Comment: Now i get it, thank you so much ,sir, hope you have a nice day

Comment: But i still confuse at question 1, i mean, why he pass `data` in this login form, what that data stand for, when it will use??

Comment: @LêQuốcKhánh no problem, based on the code sample `data` for `LOG_OUT` goes unused. So the application should theoretically work the exact same if you remove `data` entirely. The `case` in `loginReducer` is where it should be used, but it's not.

Comment: hey sir, can you help me with teamviewer or something,i can't do input anything when custom `onHandleChange` with Formik

Comment: the problem to long, i can't show here :(((